# AS400 Database access via jdbc

Tags: database, jdbc, ibm-midrange

I am trying do a query on a table via jdbc in my java program.

I know there are three rows in that table.

I've got the resultset, and can read and process data of the first row. but when I try to move the resultset to next row, an exception is thorwn.

```
the exception pointed [SQL0181]
```

Comment: Did you attempt any research on your own?  Looking up the error message perhaps?  Looked at diagnostics?  If still stumped once you've explored what you can find out on your own, then provide us with plenty of details.

Comment: the as400 system is managed by another guy, which one did't help much.

Comment: I can't even see the exception message , I am working in a very limited  environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SQL Message Finder](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzas2/rzas2finder.htm) to look up message codes.

The [SQL0181](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzala/rzalaml.htm#messages__SQL0181) message text is:

> Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid.

This indicates you have a value in a row that can not be represented as an SQL [Datetime](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzch2datetime.htm) value.

It is not uncommon for legacy HLL programs to introduce these sorts of errors as they are capable of writing directly to the table row without the same validation enforced by the SQL interface.

---

See also this previously asked SO question: [Why am I getting a “[SQL0802] Data conversion of data mapping error” exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075585/why-am-i-getting-a-sql0802-data-conversion-of-data-mapping-error-exception)

Comment: Thanks, now it's almost clear that the problem is not caused by my programe. I will bring your information to those as400 developers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's a top search result for SQL0181, and the answers is wrong.

The problem is the date being retrieved can't be represented in the date format being used.  The IBM i allows several non-ISO date formats, which can't handle things like the beginning & ending of time.  The error stems from trying to use one of them.

You can either have your user profile changed or use ISO on your JDBC settings.
"jdbc:as400://RCHASSLH;date format=iso;time format=iso;"

ref:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017268

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the other answer except maybe that it's not comprehensive. Your answer gives one _possible_ fix, though there's no evidence that it's correct for the OP.