# SQL0802 - Data Conversion or Data Mapping Error

Tags: sql, odbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm am trying to write a query that calculates some numbers on the servers side, rather than after the data is pulled.  I keep getting the SQL0802 error.  I have tried a regular `Sum` as well as `Double` and `float` commands.  I think the return is to long.  I'm using SQL Squirrel so I went and removed the decimal place restriction to see if that would fix the problem.  It is the `"Gross Margin"` calculation that is throwing it off.  The rest of the calculations work fine.  I appreciate any help i can get.  This is just a portion of the code.  I omitted the `Where`, `Group By`, and `Order By` sections for the sake of space:

```
Select  Distinct DB1.Tb1.STORE,
        DB1.Tb2.DATE_ID,

Sum (DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_SALES+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_SALES) As "Total Sales",

Sum (DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_COST+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_COST) As "Total Cost",

Sum ((DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_SALES+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_SALES)-DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_COST+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_COST)) As "Gross Profit",

Sum (((DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_SALES+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_SALES)-(DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_COST+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_COST))/(DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_SALES+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_SALES)))As "Gross Margin"
```

Comment: Is the SQLSTATE 22003?  There's a new QAQQINI setting that might address that: COLLATE_ERRORS *YES.  To help debug this, try selecting just the individual columns without the SUM or GROUP BY and see if any of them have invalid decimal data. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075585/why-am-i-getting-a-sql0802-data-conversion-of-data-mapping-error-exception) might help.

Comment: Is it possible that you're having divide-by-zero problems?  Might `CUR_CASH_Sales + CUR_CHARGE_SALES` ever be zero?

Comment: The divide-by-zero may very well be the issue.  I do believe there are instances where this is the case.  Is there anyway to handle that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the problem is divide-by-zero, you simply need to prevent the division from happening when the denominator is zero.  The easiest way would be to `sum` the numerator and denominator separately, then divide after that happens:

```
       sum (
           DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_SALES+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_SALES-
           DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_COST+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_COST
       ) /
       sum (
           DB1.Tb1.CUR_CASH_SALES+DB1.Tb1.CUR_CHARGE_SALES
       ) as "Gross Margin"
```

Then you would only get a divide-by-zero if the denominator is zero for the entire category you are grouping on.

If it is still a problem, you will need to do something else in addition.  Depending on what you want, you could:

- Use your `where` clause to exclude groups with a zero denominator from your output.
- Put a `case` statement around the entire calculation that checks if the denominator is zero before calculating.  If it is zero, replace the calculation with whatever output makes sense (zero, null, etc.).

Comment: Thanks!  After the previous comment I had used a where statement to just exclude groups with zero, but I was concerned about the accuracy of the calculations.  I believe the `case` statement should work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If divide by zero is your problem, consider that there may be no point in including rows that have no sales.

Consider using a CASE expression to do division only when the sales are not zero, but use null when the sales are zero.