# SQL CAST String to Decimal

Tags: sql, db2

> SQL0802 Data conversion or data mapping error

The fields not being `CAST` are decimals. The fields I am trying to `CAST` are strings.

I have tried different variations or `CAST` and `CONVERT` on this `case` expression.  I'm fairly certain this syntax is correct. I am still getting the error though.

```
CASE WHEN cpssn=amssn THEN amfnam||amlnam
     WHEN cpssn=CAST(maassn as DECIMAL(9)) THEN maafnm||maalnm
     WHEN cpssn=CAST(mpssno as DECIMAL(9)) THEN mppfnm||mpplnm 
END as Name
```

Comment: Which database and what is the error which you are getting?

Comment: Could you show what types of fields are `maassn` and `mpssno`? That would enable people to check whether it is even possible to cast to `DECIMAL`. The best would be an excerpt of the data contained on those columns.

Comment: Error is the top of the post,  IBM DB2 database.

Comment: Did you happen to make a change in your field types?

Comment: ForguesR,  "SQL0802 Data conversion or data mapping error." is my error message.

Comment: No change, I've triple check the data types coming from my database. "maassn" and "mpssno" are both strings.  "cpssn" and "amssn" are decimals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a "\[SQL0802\] Data conversion of data mapping error" exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075585/why-am-i-getting-a-sql0802-data-conversion-of-data-mapping-error-exception)

Comment: You have non-numeric values in your columns you're trying to CAST.

Comment: would it be easier to convert my decimals into strings?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing the values of `maassn`and `mpssno`.

Comment: Why do you store numeric data in a character column? Consider re-designing your tables when you run into problems like this.

Comment: Yes, the two fields I am trying to CAST are strings.

Comment: jarlh,  I realize this, but the design of the database is out of my control.

Comment: ForguesR, the values of the fields are sensitive data, but the length of all fields is 9, strings obviously have no precision, decimals have precision of 9.

Comment: Obviously you have a string value which can't be `CAST` to `DECIMAL(9)`.

Comment: Even if it is all numbers in the strings?

Answer (score 0):

One brute force method uses `translate()`:

```
(CASE WHEN cpssn = amssn THEN amfnam||amlnam
      WHEN length(translate(massn, 'a0123456789', 'a')) > 0 THEN NULL
      WHEN length(translate(mpssno, 'a0123456789', 'a')) > 0 THEN NULL
      WHEN cpssn = CAST(maassn as DECIMAL(9)) THEN maafnm||maalnm
      WHEN cpssn = CAST(mpssno as DECIMAL(9)) THEN mppfnm||mpplnm 
 END) as Name
```

Note: I am not intimately familiar with `translate()` in DB2.  The above uses an Oracle convention for removing characters, because the third argument cannot be `''` in Oracle.  It should still work in DB2.

This should work by first guaranteeing that the only characters in the strings are digits.  `case` is processed in sequential order, so the digit checks should be done before the conversion.